# Disable syntax guessing in kramdown

Tags: markdown, syntax-highlighting, kramdown

Our blog has lots of code examples. Because we're currently using github pages, the markdown gets rendered with kramdown+rouge.

Which brings me to my question: is it possible to make syntax-specific highlighting opt in with Kramdown?

The problem is that kramdown seems to incorrectly think that almost any code that starts with `{` is a JSON code block. This often results in "JSON error" highlighting in our posts when the contained code is not JSON.

Can I disable this syntax 'guessing' or am I stuck adding `text` language flag to incorrectly highlighted code blocks or even worse `{:.language-text}` for incorrectly highlighted code spans.

Hopefully there is an easy way to disable this.

Answer (score 2):

Kramdown has a few [options](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/options.html):

> `coderay_default_lang`
>
> Sets the default language for highlighting code blocks
>
> If no language is set for a code block, the default language is used instead. The value has to be one of the languages supported by coderay or `nil` if no default language should be used.

You can set it to `nil` and have no default, or set it to `text` to have that be the default.

> `syntax_highlighter`
>
> Set the syntax highlighter
>
> Specifies the syntax highlighter that should be used for highlighting code blocks and spans. If this option is set to `nil`, no syntax highlighting is done.
>
> Options for the syntax highlighter can be set with the `syntax_highlighter_opts` configuration option.
>
> Default: `coderay`

Set  `syntax_highlighter` to `nil` and have no syntax highlighter at all.

Or you can set it to `rouge` and pass in whatever options [Rouge](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax_highlighter/rouge.html) supports via the `syntax_highlighter_opts` configuration option. For example, the `default_lang` setting for Rouge may meet your needs.

You can set the options via the command line:

```
kramdown --coderay_default_lang=text
```

or in your Ruby code:

```
Kramdown::Document.new(source_text, {coderay_default_lang: "text"})
```

or in the document itself:

```
{::options coderay_default_lang="text" /}
```

There may be a way to pass those options on to Kramdown from the blog engine you are using, but without any indication of what you are using, all I can say is check its documentation.

Comment: Will setting a default language keep kramdown from incorrectly deciding that something is JSON? For example this inline code span `{key: value}` gets rendered as invalid JSON.

Comment: Unfortunately, there does not appear to be an option specifically to enable/disable "guessing". So all you can do is run some tests with different settings. I just checked locally, but I don't have any of the relevant ruby libs for syntax highlighting installed. Try running this command from the command line and see what you get: `echo "    {key: value}" | kramdown --coderay_default_lang=text` and compare the output with different options.

Comment: That's the conclusion I came to as well. We might disable span highlighting all-together. Having to use inline attribute lists (`{:.language-text}`) for span code elements removes much of the simplicity of markdown.

Comment: I've always been of the opinion that span highlighting was a bad idea (there's rarely enough context to guess correctly and defining the language can take more characters than the length of the span and adversely affect readability). In fact, most Markdown implementations which support code highlighting only offer support for code blocks. If Kramdown allows you to disable span highlighting separately, I would absolutely do that.